# How to parse HTML DOM and select such a element which is containing specific string?

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

There is a HTML structure like this:

```
<div>
    <b>
        <label>Company-Name : Anything</label>
    </b>
</div>
<div>
    <b>
        <label>First-Name : Alex</label>
    </b>
</div>
<div>
    <b>
        <label>Cell-phone : 035123913</label>
    </b>
</div>
```

I have this string: `First-Name :` and I need to get **Alex**. In other word, how can I search for string and then select all of that element?

**Note1:** Always this string `First-Name` is unique in the page.

**Note2:** Those elements don't have a constant order. I mean sometimes there is some new `<div><b><label>` after or before that structure. So the best option is searching for that string.

**Note3:** I'm using [this library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Correct spelling to "label" first. You can use jquery's $.each to loop through the labels. In the loop, use PHP's strpos to see if the value contains "First-name :". If it does, then you can do an explode() on it and index 1 will be the name you want.

Comment: Is the html already outputted to the browser when you want to "find it"? If it is, you'll have to use a client-side language. Jquery makes this easier, but you can use vanilla JavaScript to do the same.

Comment: Just noticed the library reference - there's good examples there of how to search for a specific element type. In your case you'll be searching for <label>. Use a standard PHP loop to loop through the array of found elements, and same methodology above applies.